# Return specific value from two level array

Tags: php, arrays

Let say if I got a set of array value which is

```
$array1=array(
“i1” => array(“v1” ,”v2”, “v3”)
, “i2” => “v4”
, “i3” => array(
[0] => “v5”
, [1] => “v6”
, [2] => “v7”
)
, “i4” => array(
[“i5”] = > “v8”
, [“i6”] => array(“v9”,”v10”)
)
)
```

How do I write to get the result of v3?

Comment: $array1[i1][2]; try this

Comment: `echo $array1["i1"][2];`

Comment: Thanks, it work already, because what  I type was echo $array1["i1"][3];

Comment: What if I was to get v6? Why echo($php_array["i3"][1]); is not working?

Comment: you can use foreach for the result of v6.

Comment: But I don't want to loop, I want the specific value, is it still necessary using the foreach loop? I thought foreach is used only when I want it to loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo $array1["i1"][2];
```

i1 is also an array with 3 value where **v3** have 2 number index

Comment: Thanks, but what if I was to get v6? Why echo($array1["i3"][1]); is not working?

Comment: is there getting any error when you try to get v6 with using echo($array1["i3"][1]);?

Comment: Yes, the error that occur was " Undefined offset: 1 "

Comment: this isn't a right way to define an array . Why did you use third bracket  in i3 array ? replace [1] => “v6” with 1=>"v6". replace all of those which belong to this format .